# Invoke-command StackOverFlowException

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, dynamics-ax-2012, invoke-command

I'm trying to use `Invoke-Command` to run a scriptblock on a remote machine.

The scriptblock is:

```
$scriptBlock = { echo Y | .\DP.EXE IMPORT $remoteExportDir 'MicrosoftDynamicsAx' $remoteMachine }
```

I run this scriptblock like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteMachine -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -AsJob
```

I run this and I can see it executing the process on the remote machine.  This command takes about 40-50 minutes to run locally.  It only runs for about 25 minutes when I do it remotely like this.

Looking at the status it says it completed with no errors but the `DP.exe` generates a log file and it's not generating it.  When I look at the output of the job I see that it failed with this message:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

`DP.EXE` is an application to import data into a test environment for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.  This command works without issue if I just run it locally on the machine.  I am attempting to write a script to run this command across a series of 5+ machines on a schedule.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this StackOverFlowException and what I can do to get by it.

Comment: Is DP.exe a program written in house?

Comment: no it is from Microsoft.  I wonder if it's a memory limit on the remote session.  I've set winrsrm/config/winrs MaxMemoryPershell to a higher limit.  I'll see if that solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was MaxMemoryPerShellMB was configured for 150mb of memory usage.  I increased this and it solved the problem.  To do this I opened powershell and put in:

winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="2000"}'

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the variables in your scriptblock. When the scriptblock is executed on the remote machine the session on that remote machine doesn't know what those variables are. In order to take care of that you need to add parameters to your scriptblock, and then pass the values into it when you invoke it on the remote machine.

```
$scriptBlock = { 
    Param(
        $remoteExportDir,
        $remoteMachine
    )
    echo Y | .\DP.EXE IMPORT $remoteExportDir 'MicrosoftDynamicsAx' $remoteMachine 
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteMachine -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -AsJob -ArgumentList $remoteExportDir,$remoteMachine
```